# XSLT transform in xmlSignature java?

Tags: java, xslt, xml-signature

I have a XML document.I am signing a part of document using xmlsignature. Before finding digest, *I want to apply XSLT transform.*
 According to what I read, XSLT converts an **XML document to another format(can be XML also).** Now I am confused that, 
**where will be the transformed new document is avilable?**
**How to retrieve the value from this newly created document if I want to show it to user?**

**My XML Document**

```
<r1>
 <user>asd</user>
 <person>ghi</person>
</r1>
```

**Code for Transformation**

```
Transform t=fac.newTransform(Transform.XPATH,new XPathFilterParameterSpec("/r1/user"));
```

According to xpath transformation,Whenever value of user element changes the xmlsignature should not be validated. And if person element's value changes then Signature should be validated. But when I change person element's value the signature is not validated. WHY?

Comment: Similar question is being asked in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680590/xslt-tranform-in-xmlsignature-form-a-part-of-xmldocument[link]. This is similar to what I want but in this link also answer is not provided :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xslt transform used when signing a document relates to how nodes in your source XML are selected when the signature is calculated.

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748642/993133) by [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3095/dave) relates to signing parts of an XML document using xpath2. The [link to Sean Mullans' post](http://markmail.org/message/tdgioazns7l4yg6d#query:java%20xpath%20xml%20dsig%20bug+page:1+mid:tgw5kr7uscwkcran+state:results) in this answer suggests xpath2 is more appropriate for signing parts of a document because the evaluation of an xpath expression is done per node.

So based on the [sun dsig example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html) you can replace the **Reference** creation using:

```
List<XPathType> xpaths = new ArrayList<XPathType>();
xpaths.add(new XPathType("//r1/user", XPathType.Filter.INTERSECT));

Reference ref = fac.newReference
  ("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
        Collections.singletonList
          (fac.newTransform(Transform.XPATH2, 
                  new XPathFilter2ParameterSpec(xpaths))),
             null, null);
```

This allows **//r1/user** to be protected with a signature while the rest of the document can be altered.

The problem with the xpath/xpath2 selection is that a signature can be generated for **/some/node/that/does/not/exist**. You are right to modify a test document and make sure the signature is working the way you expect.

You might test the document in a test program by generating a signature then tampering with the xml node before verification:

```
NodeList nlt = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
nlt.item(0).getFirstChild().setTextContent("Something else");
```

---

A more reliable alternative to an xpath selector might be to put an ID on the xml document elements you hope to sign like:

```
<r1>
 <user id="sign1">asd</user>
 <person>ghi</person>
</r1>
```

then reference this ID as the URI in the first parameter of an enveloped transfer:

```
Reference ref = fac.newReference
  ("#sign1", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
    Collections.singletonList
      (fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,(TransformParameterSpec) null)),
          null, null);
```

---

For the output, a signature operation adds a new Signature element to the DOM you have loaded in memory. You can stream the output by transforming it like this:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

Answer (score 5):

The XSLT specification doesn't define what happens to the result document; that's defined by the API specifications of your chosen XSLT processor. For example, if you invoke XSLT from Java using the JAXP interface, you can ask for the result as a DOM tree in memory or for it to be serialized to a specified file on disk.

You have tagged your question "Java" which is the only clue you give to your processing environment. My guess is you want to transform to a DOM and then use DOM interfaces to get the value from the new document. Though if you're using XSLT 2.0 and Saxon, the s9api interface is much more usable than the native JAXP interface.

Comment: please see this link - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html . It gives the xml signature api in java. But there is not mention of xslt there.  For trasform only enveloping, enveloped and detached options are available. Where should the xslt code be inserted?

Answer (score 3):

The xslt part defines only the transformation definition, nothing else. 
Have a look at this:

[java xslt tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968040/java-xslt-tutorial)

in Francois Gravel answer the input.xml file is the file that will be transformed, the transform.xslt is the xslt definition which describes how to transform the xml file. output.out are the results, this may be xml, but it can also be html, flat file...

This is where I started with when i was using xslt:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp

Have a look at this also:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with xslt as far as i see.

Comment: yes I know. I have mentioned that in the comment. What I am asking is how to use xslt in xml signatures in java. I want a sample code or a link containing a sample code.